# which is the relationship between infinite set and the orbits of their points?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I have been studying the proof of the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let's suppose that $X$ is some metric space and $X$ is a infinite set. If $f:X\to X$ is transitive and has dense periodic points then $f$ has sensitive dependence on initial conditions.

It was proved by J. Banks, Here's [a link](http://www.cwu.edu/~lundin/Courses/math332/Transitivity%20and%20Periodic%20points%20implies%20sensitivity.pdf)

Almost all the proof is clear, but I can't understand how it's possible to choose two arbitrary periodic points $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ with disjoint orbits $\mathcal{O}(q_{1},f)$ and $\mathcal{O}(q_{2},f)$. I know that this is related to the fact that $X$ is a infinite set, but i don't see it!

Also, I have the following question:

**Question 2:** Suppose that $q_{1},q_{2}\in Per(f)$, i.e, exists $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{n}(q_{1})=q_{1}$ and $f^{m}(q_{2})=q_{2}$. If $X$ is infinite or finite, which is the relationship between $\mathcal{O}(q_{1},f)$ and $\mathcal{O}(q_{2},f)$?.

1. $\mathcal{O}(q_{1},f)\cap \mathcal{O}(q_{2},f)\neq \emptyset$.
2. If $n<m$ or $n>m$, $\mathcal{O}(q_{1},f)\subset \mathcal{O}(q_{2},f)$
3. etc,..

I've been thinking on and off about this questions for a couple of days,...

Answer (score 5):

Take any periodic point $q_1$.  Its orbit is a finite set, and therefore is not dense.  So there must be another periodic point $q_2$ whose orbit is not $\mathcal O(q_1, f)$.  But the orbits of periodic points are either the same or disjoint.

Comment: One should mention that the reason finite sets are not dense is a consequence of the fact that $X$ is both infinite and a metric space. If $X$ is not metric, then one can cook up a topological space such that a finite set is dense - For instance if $D$ is the closed unit disc in the plane and $I(D)$ is its interior, then the point $[I(D)]$ in the quotient space $D/I(D)$ is dense.

Comment: More generally, a topological space $X$ is a $T_1$ space iff no subspace of $X$ has a dense finite proper subset.

Comment: Robert Israel, for your argument it's possible choose $q_{2}$ such that $q_{2}\notin \mathcal{O}(q_{1},f)$ . But, how i can guarantee that $\mathcal{O}(q_{1},f) \cap \mathcal{O}(q_{2},f)=\emptyset$ ?. I think the problem remains the same or not?

Comment: If $q$ is periodic and $r \in \mathcal O(q, f)$, then there is some $m$ such that $f^m(r) = q$.  
Suppose $q_3 \in \mathcal O(q_1, f) \cap \mathcal O(q_2,f)$, where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are periodic.  Since $q_2$ is periodic and $q_3 \in \mathcal O(q_2, f)$,  $f^m(q_3) = q_2$ for some $m$.  But since $f$ maps $\mathcal O(q_1, f)$ to itself, that says $q_2 \in \mathcal O(q_1,f)$.  Similarly $q_1 \in \mathcal O(q_2,f)$, and the orbits are the same.